# How to randomly select an element in a 2D numpy array in the same row or column of specified element using vectorization?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a 2D NumPy array (say `arr1`) containing values `0` or `1` as float values. Let size of `arr1` be `h x w`. I have another NumPy array (say `arr2`) of size `n x 2`, where each row specifies a location (row and column index) in `arr1`. For every `arr1` location (say `(x1, y1)` ) specified by each row of `arr2`, I need to select another location (say `(x2, y2)`) in `arr1` which is in the same row or column as `(x1, y1)`, such that there is atleast one cell between `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`, including these two cells, whose value in `arr1` is 1.
How can I achieve this efficiently in time? Typical values of `h,w,n` are `800,800,500000` respectively. So, I would like to achieve this without any for loops.

**Example:**

```
import numpy

h=4
w=4
n=3
arr1 = numpy.array([
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
      ])
arr2 = numpy.array([
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [0, 2],
      ])
```

**Expected solution:**
First row of `arr2` is `(1,1)`. Valid solutions in 2nd column as `(0,1), (2,1), (3,1)` and valid solutions in 2nd row are `(1,0), (1,2), (1,3)`. So the code should randomly pick one of these.
Similar for second row of `arr2` which is `(2,2)`, valid solutions are `(0,2), (1,2), (3,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,3)`.
For third row of `arr2` which is `(0,2)`, valid solutions are `(0,0),(0,1),(1,2),(2,2),(3,2)`. Note that `(0,3)` is not a valid solution since there is no cell containing `1` between `(0,2)` and `(0,3)`.

Note that if a row in `arr2` is `(0,3)`, there is no cell in that column with the value `1`. Such cases are extremely rare and in such cases, it suffices to pick a location that is sufficiently far away in that column. It is not necessary to detect such cases and pick a location in the same row.

PS: I have a solution by iterating over each row of `arr2`, but that takes over 1 minute. I am looking for a vectorized solution

Answer (score 0):

I tried writing a solution to this using vectorization, but it still need to uses masked reduce operations which makes things way slower than normal broadcasting

The basic idea behind what i did is to rotate every row by the col index in `arr2` and find the min/max index of a non 0 element. Than you select a random number between this 2 (all possible rotated solutions) and rotate it back to get the actual solution for that row.
You than do the same on the transposed `arr1` and `arr2` to get the the solution by columns and than you randomly select if you want the row or colum solution.

Still this take ~`26s` to execute

PS: If no solution is possible for the initial point (both row and col are all zeros), a -1 will appear in those coordinates

```
import time
import numpy as np

def get_same_row_random(arr, pos, shift):
    width = arr.shape[1]
    app1 = -np.ones_like(arr, dtype=np.int64)
    app2 = np.zeros_like(arr, dtype=np.bool8)
    w1 = np.where(arr == 1)
    app1[w1] = w1[1]
    app2[w1] = True

    res = app1[pos]
    mask = app2[pos]

    mask[np.arange(shift.size), shift] = False # Can't select original coordinates
    res = (res - shift.reshape(-1,1)) % width
    res_min = np.min(res, initial=width, where=mask, axis=1)
    res_max = np.max(res, initial=-1, where=mask, axis=1)

    w = (res_min == width)
    res_min[w] = -1
    res_max += 1

    res = (np.random.randint(res_min, res_max) + shift) % width
    res[w] = -1

    return res

h, w, n = 800,800, 500000
arr1 = np.random.randint(2, size=(h,w))
arr2_1 = np.random.randint(h, size=n)
arr2_2 = np.random.randint(w, size=n)
arr2 = np.vstack((arr2_1, arr2_2)).T

start = time.time()

row_indexes = get_same_row_random(arr1, arr2[:,0], arr2[:,1])
col_indexes = get_same_row_random(arr1.T, arr2[:,1], arr2[:,0])

r_or_c = np.random.randint(2, size=n)
exc_row = np.where(row_indexes == -1)[0]
exc_col = np.where(col_indexes == -1)[0]
r_or_c[exc_row] = 1
r_or_c[exc_col] = 0

wr = np.where(r_or_c == 0)[0]
wc = np.where(r_or_c == 1)[0]
res = np.array(arr2)
res[wr,1] = row_indexes[wr]
res[wc,0] = col_indexes[wc]

end = time.time()
```